# CruiseControl.NET 1.8.5 - Not creating msbuild-results xml file

Tags: msbuild, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, specflow

I'm pretty new to build servers but have been asked by my employer to do some testing (because F5 is not a build process, as the excellent article by Jeff Atwood says). At this stage, I'm working on getting some sample builds and test reports up and running on a CruiseControl.NET server. So far, I've gotten a build up and running (the configuration file will need some tidying up before adding new builds/projects but the proof of concept is there) but the reporting is causing something of a headache.

The main report I'm looking for is for out NUnit tests and SpecFlow integration tests. The tests run fine (as I'm getting a sensible looking xml file generated) and am looking to merge that in to the main build results so that I can show the results of the NUnit/SpecFlowtests.

Whenever the build completes, the following is reported in the messages (in ViewFarmReport.aspx): "Failing Tasks : XmlLogPublisher "

This combined with the following error reported in the Windows application log (source - CC.Net)

> 2015-03-24 08:36:52,987 [Initech.SuperCrm-DEV] ERROR CruiseControl.NET [(null)] - Publisher threw exception: ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Unable to read the contents of the file: C:\CCNet\BuildArtifacts\Initech.SuperCrm-DEV\msbuild-results-7c657954-2c3e-405f-b0f1-7da1299788fd.xml ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\CCNet\BuildArtifacts\Initech.SuperCrm-DEV\msbuild-results-7c657954-2c3e-405f-b0f1-7da1299788fd.xml'.

(company/application name "censored")

This leads me to suspect that the failure to merge in the msbuild results (which I believe CruiseControl.NET automatically scrapes since version... 1.5 or 1.6?) is preventing the NUnit results from being merged in.

There is no msbuild-results file in the BuildArtifacts folder, which does not surprise me as I do not believe my current msbuild configuration allows for xml based logging as I am using the ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll logger.

According to the online documentation for CruiseControl.NET there is XML enabled custom logger: ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger which can be used, however the download location for this logger: [here](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/MSBuildXmlLogger-Builds/)

appears not to exist any more.

Can anyone say whether I'm thinking along the right lines here and what my options are?

For reference, here is my complete configuration:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

    <cb:define MSBuildPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" />
    <cb:define WorkingBaseDir="C:\CCNet\Builds" />
    <cb:define ArtifactBaseDir="C:\CCNet\BuildArtifacts" />
    <cb:define MSBuildLogger="C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server

\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll" />
    <cb:define NUnitExe="C:\Jenkins\Nunit\nunit-console.exe" />

    <cb:define name="vsts_ci">
        <executable>C:\Jenkins\tf.exe</executable>
        <server>http://tfs-srv:8080/tfs/LEEDS/</server>
        <domain>CONTOSO</domain>
        <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
        <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
        <force>true</force>
        <deleteWorkspace>true</deleteWorkspace>
    </cb:define>



    <project name="Initech.Libraries" description="Shared libraries used in all Initech projects" 

queue="Q1">
        <state type="state" directory="C:\CCNet\State"/>
        <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactBaseDir)\Initech.Libraries</artifactDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>$(WorkingBaseDir)\Initech.Libraries</workingDirectory>

        <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger
            name="continuous"
            seconds="30"
            buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
            initialSeconds="5"/>
        </triggers>

        <sourcecontrol type="vsts">
            <cb:vsts_ci/>
            <workspace>CCNET_Initech.Libraries</workspace>
            <project>$/InitechLibraries/Initech.Libraries</project>
        </sourcecontrol>
    </project>

  <project name="Initech.SuperCrm-DEV" description="Initech.SuperCrm Application, Development 

Version" queue="Q1">

    <cb:define ArtifactDirectory="$(ArtifactBaseDir)\Initech.SuperCrm-DEV" />
    <cb:define WorkingDirectory="$(WorkingBaseDir)\Initech.SuperCrm-DEV" />
    <cb:define OutputDirectory="$(WorkingDirectory)\Initech.SuperCrm\bin\Debug" />
    <cb:define ProjectFile="Initech.SuperCrm.sln" />
    <cb:define NUnitLog="$(WorkingDirectory)\NunitResults.xml" />

    <state type="state" directory="C:\CCNet\State"/>
    <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactDirectory)</artifactDirectory>
    <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDirectory)</workingDirectory>

    <triggers>
      <!-- check the source control every X time for changes, 
         and run the tasks if changes are found -->
      <intervalTrigger
               name="continuous"
               seconds="30"
               buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
               initialSeconds="5"/>
    </triggers>

    <sourcecontrol type="vsts">
        <cb:vsts_ci/>
        <workspace>CCNET_Initech.SuperCrm-DEV</workspace>
        <project>$/InitechSuperCrm/SuperCrm/Initech.SuperCrm-DEV</project>
    </sourcecontrol>

    <tasks>
        <exec>
            <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\DXperience 12.1\Tools\DXperience

\ProjectConverter-console.exe</executable>
            <buildArgs>$(WorkingDirectory)</buildArgs>
        </exec>

        <msbuild>           
            <executable>$(MSBuildPath)\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDirectory)</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>$(ProjectFile)</projectFile>   
            <timeout>900</timeout>
            <logger>$(MSBuildLogger)</logger>
        </msbuild>

        <exec>
            <executable>$(NUnitExe)</executable>
            <buildArgs>/xml=$(NUnitLog) /nologo $(WorkingDirectory)\$(ProjectFile)

</buildArgs>
        </exec>
    </tasks>

    <publishers>
        <buildpublisher>
            <sourceDir>$(OutputDirectory)</sourceDir>
            <useLabelSubDirectory>true</useLabelSubDirectory>
            <alwaysPublish>false</alwaysPublish>
            <cleanPublishDirPriorToCopy>true</cleanPublishDirPriorToCopy>
        </buildpublisher>

        <merge>
            <files>
              <file>$(NUnitLog)</file>
            </files>
        </merge>

      <xmllogger logDir="C:\CCNet\BuildArtifacts\Initech.SuperCrm-DEV\buildlogs" />

      <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                       cleanUpValue="50" />
    </publishers>

  </project>

</cruisecontrol>
```

I've been tearing my hair while trying to figure this out, and I don't have much to begin with, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a prolonged period of banging my head against the wall, I seem to have finally found the solution (well solutions).

1) Kobush.Build.dll (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kobush.Build/) can be used as the logger for MSBuild. Looking at the attributions in CruiseControl.NET's documentation, it appears to have been written by the same developer (but extended).

2) Some tweaks were needed due to the default location of the msbuild-report output. Because, by default, it was dumped to the buildartifacts folder then it is susceptible to being prematurely deleted.

I no longer clean the publish directory prior to copying (in the buildpublisher) and perform the merge and xmllogger portions of the publisher before artifact cleanup.

As a result, I now have msbuild and nunit output/results integrated in to the main build log and these can be consumed through the CruiseControl.NET dashboard.

There's probably a tidier way of handling this, but at the moment I'm just getting a proof of concept going.

Comment: I would encourage you to think of CC.NET as a "super fancy msbuild.exe excecutor".........write a mysolution.proj file, and put msbuild code in this file............put this file in the same directory as your .sln file.  have CC.NET pull this file (using your source control task for choice)...and then running msbuild.exe "mysolution.proj"......this way..you're minimizing the number of cc.net proprietary tasks you use.